# Scraping Twitter Image Object URLs with Scrapy in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, twitter, scrapy

I write a program using Selenium and Scrapy to scrape the images URLs of a specific Twitter profile. I coded Selenium to access the profile, but I keep failing scraping the URLs of the images. Since each URL starts with 'https://pbs.twimg.com', my aim is to extract each element containing that text.

I tried the following code:

```
sel = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
image_url = sel.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'https://pbs.twimg.com')]").extract()
for image in image_url:
    yield {'Image': image}
```

I don't get any error when I run it, but my output file is just empty. Is my xPath wrong? Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Ok so by modifying the code as such `image_url = sel.xpath("//img/@src").extract()` , I can actually scrape the urls. Now the only problem is that I want only the ones containing 'https://pbs.twimg.com', otherwise I also get all emojis etc. Any suggestion to build the 'contains' method in this line of code?

Comment: The "text" of a tag is the stuff between the marks:`<p>this is text</p>`.  You want to find an `<img>` tag where the `src` attribute contains that text.

Comment: As OP mentioned in previous comments it should be `src` attribute and your xpath should be `image_url = sel.xpath("//*[contains(@src,'https://pbs.twimg.com')]").extract()`

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. I changed the code, but somehow i still get an empty output file.

Comment: Ok so by modifying the code as such `image_link = sel.xpath("//img/@src").extract()` , I can actually scrape the urls. Now the only problem is that I want only the ones containing 'https://pbs.twimg.com', otherwise I also get all emojis etc. Any suggestion for this last bit?

Comment: page_source doesn't do what you think it does. It rarely returns the entire dom.

Answer (score 0):

page_source is rarely the complete page. Try this:

```
elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath ("//img[contains(text(),'https://pbs.twimg.com')]")
for element in elements
    print(element.get_attribute('src'))
```